How do I access batched image filenames while using 'image_dataset_from_directory'?
I have a database of images that are close to 10 million images. I am using the classical definition below to build a dataset:
trainData = image_dataset_from_directory(
                                directory=TRAINING_DIR,
                                labels='inferred',
                                label_mode='categorical',
                                class_names=['01', '02', '03'],
                                color_mode='grayscale',
                                batch_size=Batch_Size,
                                image_size=Img_Size,
                                shuffle=False,
                                seed=42,
                                validation_split=None,
                                subset=None,
                                interpolation='bilinear',
                                follow_links=False,
                                crop_to_aspect_ratio=False) 

and try to streamline disk access by utilizing a more efficient pipeline by utilizing 'prefetch':
trainData = trainData.take(Batch_Size).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

and then finally request a batch of these images utilizing an iterator:
X_train, Y_train = trainData.as_numpy_iterator().next()

This is all good and works well and let's me have access to my batched 'features' (X_train) as well as my batched 'targets' (Y_train).
My problem is the following: I need to also know which 'filenames' were batched to provide me with those 'features' (X_train) as well as my batched 'targets' (Y_train).
I tried various flavours of the following thought process with mixed degrees of failure:
trainData_filenames = trainData.file_paths

trainData_filenames = trainData.list_files


The final Dataset you get with this function does not contain the image paths information anymore. It get's used to load the image, but in the end you only get the tensors. If you use shuffle=False, you can re-construct the batches with the order of the images/folder in the data storage.

Thank you for your response mhenning. I fully understand the 1st part of your answer. I am not sure how to proceed with the information in the 2nd part of your answer! How do I re-construct the batches with the order of images/folder? Do you mean conduct a blind pull on the files name corresponding to the batch file size sequentially?

Because you use shuffle=False in your example, you simply can scan your data directory. Lets say you have 3 class folders with 10 jpg samples each in it and a bautch size of 16. Then the first batch of the Dataset would contain class_0/0.jpg, class_0/1.jpg, ...,  class_0/9.jpg,  class_1/0.jpg, ..., class_1/5.jpg. The second batch would begin with class_1/6.jpg. This only holds if you don't shuffle, and the images are read in the same order theyy are read in image_dataset_from_directory..

Another solution would be to take a look at the image_dataset_from_directory function and write your own solution, which retains the image path belonging to the image. If it helps you, this line in a helper method "overwrites" the image path with the actual image.
